# iOS how to data store permanently, even if the app is unstalled and if the phone is restored

Tags: ios, memory, permanent

I need to store (few bytes) data permanently to save an app state or rights. If the app is uninstalled and re-installed, I need to read back the data. Even if the phone is restored with iTunes.

Is it possible?

Comment: to store data into keychain [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459879/how-to-store-a-string-in-keychain-ios)

Comment: And iCloud is also an option I guess.

Comment: If you want to recover the data after the phone is restored then you have to save it off the device.  This means you need some form of user account or use the iCloud account, but it becomes difficult to tell the difference between a device that has been restored and multiple devices with the same account.